# Vlookup to external file in a VBA formula

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am a beginner with VBA, and I'm currently building formulas to simplify processes.
I'm trying to build a "GetName" formula that would actually be a VLOOKUP to an external file,and pick the name of a product in another file, using the reference.

The simple VLOOKUP formula would be :

=VLOOKUP(A2;'[General Database data.xlsx]GD'!$B:$C;2;FALSE)

```
 
Public Function GetName(sku As String)
    Dim myTableArray As Range

    With Workbooks("..\Desktop\General Database data.xlsx").Worksheets("GD")
        Set myTableArray = .Range("B:C")
    End With
    
    GetName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sku, myTableArray, 2, False)
End Function
```

Is it possible ? Can I make it into a simple formula ?

Comment: When you say "an external file" do you mean an unopened workbook?

Comment: Exactly, in another folder

Comment: But, I suppose that you know that it is not possible to do it without opening the workbook... So, the code should check if the workbook is open. If yes, use it, if not open it and use it after. Is this what you need?

Comment: And if my supposition is correct, you can build such a function, but not a UDF type one. I mean, not to be called from a cell...

Comment: I doubted it, but I thought I could find a workaround. Is there any way than Vlookup to connect the formula to some kind of database ? Ideally, I'd like to avoid any extra step for the user.